# Is my LUKS header damaged? "Device... is too small..."

Tags: dual-boot, mount, encryption, luks

It's a 38 GB partition, still showing in fdisk as 38 GB.
On entering

```
$sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb2 ext
```

I get:

```
Device /dev/sdb2 is too small. (LUKS requires at least 1049600 bytes.)
```

I can't imagine what could have happened, EXCEPT that I've been trying to also mount it in Windows 10 (dual-boot) and found that Libre Crypt no longer works; it says that the drive is mounted, but I have no way to access it, as ext2fs is no longer working on this new Windows installation. I only successfully mounted it on Windows 7, before "up"grading to 10. Libre Crypt still says that the passcode is correct and shows it as mounted, and unmounts it normally.
Under Linux, I get the above error message for any attempted LUKS operation, and yes, this only started after the "up" grade.

From what I've read, it does sound like that would be a corrupted header. Is there another way to check?

Many thanks!

(P.S. In this particular case, it is not much actual data and not that urgent, but I still want to know more.)

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04 after upgrading to kernel 5.3.0-46-generic #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu.
On kernel 4.17 I was able to do the persistent partition, encrypted or not. Maybe is the kernel or you have to substitute sudo with su, you have to try this.